Page Unresponsive when Lightning Data table have more column
Im dynamically creating columns in lightning data table for each year months with infinite loading.
ex. the table should look like below
Year-2021 Jan-21 Feb-21....Dec-21 Year-2022 Jan-22 Feb-22...Dec-22 goes on for each years
15000     5000   5000      5000   6000      2000   2000     2000
The table is rendering till 700records without any issues, when i scroll the page becomes unresponsive. how can i optimize to load more data?
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getRevenues from '@salesforce/apex/RevenueFlashController.getRevenues';

export default class RevenueFlash extends LightningElement {
   @track data = [];
   @track orginaldata = [];
   rowSize = 50;
   rowOffset = 0;

  @track columns = [
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Name of the Customer', fieldName: 'Name_of_the_Customer__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'BU Name', fieldName: 'BU_Name__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'OPP Id', fieldName: 'Opp_ID__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Probability%', fieldName: 'Probability__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Entity', fieldName: 'Entity__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Project Name', fieldName: 'Project_Name__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Customer Category', fieldName: 'Customer_Category__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue Type', fieldName: 'EB_EEB__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue Modal', fieldName: 'Revenue_Model__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'WBS Code', fieldName: 'WBS_Code__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue Start Date', fieldName: 'SOW_Start_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue End Date', fieldName: 'SOW_End_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Opportunity SOW Start Date', fieldName: 'Opportunity_SOW_Start_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Opportunity SOW End Date', fieldName: 'Opportunity_SOW_End_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Deal Value', fieldName: 'Revenue_Amount__c', typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
    ];

    @track adjustcolumns = [
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Name of the Customer', fieldName: 'Name_of_the_Customer__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'BU Name', fieldName: 'BU_Name__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'OPP Id', fieldName: 'Opp_ID__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Probability%', fieldName: 'Probability__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Entity', fieldName: 'Entity__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Project Name', fieldName: 'Project_Name__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Customer Category', fieldName: 'Customer_Category__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue Type', fieldName: 'EB_EEB__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue Modal', fieldName: 'Revenue_Model__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'WBS Code', fieldName: 'WBS_Code__c' },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue Start Date', fieldName: 'SOW_Start_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Revenue End Date', fieldName: 'SOW_End_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Opportunity SOW Start Date', fieldName: 'Opportunity_SOW_Start_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Opportunity SOW End Date', fieldName: 'Opportunity_SOW_End_Date__c', type: "date", typeAttributes: { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" } },
        { initialWidth: 200, label: 'Deal Value', fieldName: 'Revenue_Amount__c' },
    ];

   connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener("click", this.hideDropdown.bind(this));
        this.isListening = true;
        this.loadData();
        this.loadPicklistOptions();
    }

  async loadData() {
        try {
            let data = await getRevenues({
                limitSize: this.rowSize,
                offset: this.rowOffset,
                fromDate: this.fromDate,
                oppfromDate: this.oppfromDate,
                toDate: this.toDate,
                opptoDate: this.opptoDate,
                customerlst: this.allValues,
                problst: this.proballValues,
                revmodallst: this.revallValues,
                bunamelists: this.BUallValues,
                entitylists: this.entallValues,
                EEB: this.EBallValues,
                cuscategory: this.categoryallValues
            });
            if (data) {
                this.orginaldata = [...this.orginaldata, ...data];
                const processedData = this.processData(this.orginaldata);
                this.data = [...this.data, ...processedData];
                this.assignColumns(this.data);

                this.enableInfiniteLoading = data.length === this.rowSize;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong ' + error);
        }
    }

    async loadMoreData(event) {
        let target = event.target;
        target.isLoading = true;

        this.rowOffset += this.rowSize;
        await this.loadData();

        target.isLoading = false;
    }

    processData(revenueData) {
        const processedData = [];

        revenueData.forEach(record => {
            const baseRecord = {
                BU_Name__c: record.BU_Name__c,
                Customer_Category__c: record.Customer_Category__c,
                Revenue_Amount__c: record.Revenue_Amount__c,
                EB_EEB__c: record.EB_EEB__c,
                Entity__c: record.Entity__c,
                Name_of_the_Customer__c: record.Name_of_the_Customer__c,
                Opp_ID__c: record.Opp_ID__c,
                Opportunity_Name__c: record.Opportunity_Name__c,
                Probability__c: record.Probability__c,
                Project_Name__c: record.Project_Name__c,
                Revenue_Model__c: record.Revenue_Model__c,
                SOW_Start_Date__c: record.SOW_Start_Date__c,
                SOW_End_Date__c: record.SOW_End_Date__c,
                Opportunity_SOW_End_Date__c: record.Opportunity_SOW_End_Date__c,
                WBS_Code__c: record.WBS_Code__c
            };

            const fiscalYearTotals = {};
            let totalRevenueSum = 0;

            if (record.Revenue_Report__r && record.Revenue_Report__r.length > 0) {
                record.Revenue_Report__r.forEach(revenue => {
                    const monthKey = revenue.Revenue_Month__c;
                    baseRecord[monthKey] = revenue.Revenue_Amount__c;
                    const [month, year] = monthKey.split(' ');
                    const amount = parseFloat(baseRecord[monthKey]) || 0;
                    totalRevenueSum += amount;
                    let fiscalYear;
                    if (['January', 'February', 'March'].includes(month)) {
                        fiscalYear = `${year - 1}-${year}`;
                    } else {
     
                   fiscalYear = `${year}-${parseInt(year) + 1}`;
                    }

                    if (!fiscalYearTotals[fiscalYear]) {
                        fiscalYearTotals[fiscalYear] = 0;
                    }
                    fiscalYearTotals[fiscalYear] += amount;
                });
            }

            Object.keys(fiscalYearTotals).forEach(fiscalYear => {
                baseRecord[fiscalYear] = fiscalYearTotals[fiscalYear];
            });
            baseRecord['SUM_of_Revenue'] = totalRevenueSum;
            baseRecord['Difference'] = (parseFloat(record.Revenue_Amount__c) || 0) - totalRevenueSum;
            processedData.push(baseRecord);
        });

        return processedData;
    }

    assignColumns(data) {
        this.columns = [...this.adjustcolumns];

        const monthColumns = [...new Set(data.flatMap(record =>
            Object.keys(record).filter(key => key.match(/^[A-Za-z]+ \d{4}$/))
        ))].map(month => ({
            initialWidth: 200,
            label: month,
            fieldName: month,
            type: 'number'
        })).sort((a, b) => {
            const [monthA, yearA] = a.label.split(' ');
            const [monthB, yearB] = b.label.split(' ');

            const dateA = new Date(`${monthA} 1, ${yearA}`);
            const dateB = new Date(`${monthB} 1, ${yearB}`);

            return dateA - dateB;
        });

        const fiscalYearColumns = [...new Set(data.flatMap(record =>
            Object.keys(record).filter(key => key.includes('-'))
        ))].map(year => ({
            initialWidth: 200,
            label: `FY ${year}`,
            fieldName: year,
            type: 'number'
        })).sort((a, b) => {
            const yearA = parseInt(a.label.split(' ')[1], 10);
            const yearB = parseInt(b.label.split(' ')[1], 10);

            return yearA - yearB;
        });

        const additionalColumns = [
            { label: 'SUM of Revenue', fieldName: 'SUM_of_Revenue', type: 'number', initialWidth: 200 },
            { label: 'Difference', fieldName: 'Difference', type: 'number', initialWidth: 200 }
        ];

        this.columns = [...this.columns, ...fiscalYearColumns, ...monthColumns, ...additionalColumns];
    }


}

Regards,
Afrose

Do you have checked this? - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000G5I1KSAV - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000742642&type=1

Hi @TusharJadav,
Thanks for your response, Yes i go throgh the document but in my case i need to show more columns, Not sure how to optimize.

You need to cause earlier columns to be unloaded as you load new ones. Fundamentally you are overloading the browsers rendering engine.

Hi Afrose, I am not sure if a user need to view 700 rows of data, I think it is better to implement a pagination, with filters, where they can apply certain filters and view the data they want to view.

Hi @PhilW, Thanks for your response, yes exactly right way, I'm looking the way to unload data, even I added infinite loading with row limit 2,  but Im looking the way to user see all the data in UI but in the backend process only requested data should be processed and add it to the existing data. Do you suggest any idea process only new data and add it into the existing data ?
